# Failing to install doc-base

Tags: apt, 15.04

When trying to

```
sudo apt-get install libbz2-dev
```

I get an error related to doc-base

```
Setting up doc-base (0.10.6) ...
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
dpkg: error processing package doc-base (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 139
Errors were encountered while processing:
 doc-base
```

What is wrong?

Comment: That had no effect. I needed to remove files as mentioned in the answer below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should work:

```
sudo rm /var/lib/dpkg/info/doc-base.*
sudo apt-get install --reinstall doc-base
```

Comment: This worked for me when I removed the --reinstall flag and simply installed.  `sudo apt-get install doc-base`

Comment: @Selah `--reinstall` should not be a problem …

Comment: It was for me!  But perhaps my issue was slightly different than the one here.  Here is the error I got:  `E: Internal Error, No file name for doc-base:amd64`

Comment: @Selah Anyway you have my upvote [here](http://askubuntu.com/a/634716/367165)